# Ocr train solution for tesseract

Tags: tesseract

Installing and using any trainer for tesseract

I was searching for a solution to train my tesseract and create a language file, now for 3 months, am not a professional programmer so am trying to learn, I need it to build an automatic solution for a project I have, but I didn't found any tutor video or any topic about installing any train extension or software and use , am using spider and python 3 , and have download qt,tests and other but how to use.
I need tutor any documentary can help, like box creating, export and test my file as language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

You can use JTessBoxEditor.

1)Provide the image

2)Generate boxes

3)Train your tesseract with generated boxes.

These are the steps.

Also you can train using txt file. Here is tutorial about it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_1-hGsXxy8